# GIT commit commands equivalent of SVN commands

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am doing a migration of SVN to GIT for one of my project.
One of the place i have the below liner code for the SVN update

```
svn commit --no-auth-cache --message "commit test" --file test.properties --force-log --username XXXX --password XXXXX
```

So just wanted to check what is the equivalent GIT command that i should use.
Till now i have got till the below part

```
git commit -m "commit test" --file test.properties
```

So how can i append the username/password tag in the GIT commit command so that it can use the same for authentication while accessing the repo.

Thanks
-Sam

Comment: Making a commit in Git and accessing the repo are two different operations.  Are you asking about how you can cache your credentials to use when you communicate with the repo?

Comment: You can't: the nature of a Git commit is different from the nature of an SVN commit. An SVN commit must contact a central repository on some server, to obtain permission and a revision number. Git is distributed in nature; there may not be a central repository at all, and the commit happens locally, with no central server.

Comment: Agreed .. So just correct me if i am wrong.. So my query is then if we do a commit through git also the content will be located in some repo and if i want to do a git commit for performing some update i need to pass some authentication process which i can do through the Id's. So just wanted to know how can i achieve the same.

Comment: As a general comment, please don't try to map svn/cvs to git command by command. The way these two things work is quite different and you'll end up with a lot breakages. I'd recommend you look through your svn automation and make a conceptual picture of what it's doing then  translate that back into git.

Comment: yes fully agreed @NoufalIbrahim

Answer (score 2):

> So my query is then if we do a commit through git also the content will be located in some repo

The commit will be located in the repo on the machine where you created the commit. In SVN, `commit` is a verb that saves your changes to the Subversion repository, which is generally on some other machine. In git, `commit` is a verb, but it's also a noun -- *a commit* is a specific set of changes that you create, which are applied together. When you use the `git commit` command, you create *a commit* in the local repo. You can then use `git push` to send the commit (or commits) that you've created to another repo, such as one that you share with the rest of your team.

> So how can i append the username/password tag in the GIT commit command so that it can use the same for authentication while accessing the repo.

This seems like the heart of your question. You can include the user and password in the URL for the repo when you push, like:

```
git push https://user:password@repomachinename.yourcompany.com/reponame.git
```

where `user` is the username, `password` is the corresponding password, and the rest is just the hostname and path to the repository you're pushing to. And again, git works differently, so creating the commit and moving it to the shared repo are two separate steps.

Note also that the `--file` option doesn't do what you seem to think it does; in git, `--file` doesn't specify the file to add to the repo, rather it causes the commit message to be read from a file.

To put it all together, after modifying file `test.properties`, you'd do something like:

```
git add test.properties
git commit -m "commit test"
git push https://user:password@repomachinename.yourcompany.com/reponame.git
```

Comment: very well explained .. @Caleb

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide any credentials to create a commit in Git. Are you asking how you can inline the identity with which the commit is created? Then you can use `git -c user.name="John Doe" -c user.email=john.doe@example.com commit ...`. If you are asking on how to get the commit to some central repository, you also have to do a push after the commit.